# Using GWT with SEAM

Tags: gwt, seam

I want to use GWT with seam Framework, so i add the jar gwt-user-2.2.0.jar to my project. but when i invoke any method from the view (a xhtml page ) this exception is occured:

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: ERROR: GWT.create() is only usable in client code!  It cannot be called, for example, from server code.  If you are running a unit test, check that your test case extends GWTTestCase and that GWT.create() is not called from within an initializer or constructor.
>       at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:92)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.UIObject.(UIObject.java:188)
>       ... 84 more

I use seam v2.2,I can post the code :

```
    @Name("scheduleHandler1")
public class SheduleHandler1 implements Serializable,EntryPoint
{   
public void onModuleLoad() {
        MyPopup p = new MyPopup();

            RootPanel.get().add(p);
          }
```

From my xhtml view i call this method:

```
 <h:commandLink value="showPopup" action="#{scheduleHandler1.onModuleLoad}" />
```

Thanks for Help.

Comment: Which version of Seam? v2 or v3?

Comment: Can you post an example of your code that is causing the problem please?  It's hard to see what the problem is if we can't see the code that may contain the problem.

Comment: I use seam v2.2,I can post the code :

        @Name("scheduleHandler1")
    public class SheduleHandler1 implements Serializable,EntryPoint
    { 
    public void onModuleLoad() {
      MyPopup p = new MyPopup();
    
          RootPanel.get().add(p);
        }


From my xhtml view i call this method:

     <h:commandLink value="showPopup" action="#{scheduleHandler1.onModuleLoad}" />

Comment: How'd you go getting an answer to this question?

Comment: Hi Aaron, unfortunately i have not found a solution to this question and i have not time also to find how to resolve it,so i worked with the richfaces modal panel with it  i can show a popup from the server side.

Answer (score 0):

GWT is client side technology - the java code that you write compiles down to js+html and is executed inside the browser.

OTOH, SEAM is server side technology - code that you write executes on server when a request is made and the HTML is produced which is returned back to browser for display.

In this sense GWT and Seam do not go well together. Most certainly you can not mix the code in the same compile unit.

You *could* use Seam for server side REST and GWT on the client side to consume REST, but this would only make sense if you already had an existing Seam REST code.

If you have written some GWT code and want to include it in you html pages (static or produced by Seam) then use them as GWT host pages - you simply include script tag to include GWT js code in the page: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html

Answer (score 0):

GWT and Seam can actually work together, as you can see in this page in the [Seam Reference Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.0.0.GA/reference/en/html/gwt.html).

However, what it looks like you are trying to do, and where the problem looks to me, is that you are trying to mix JSF and GWT.  You are trying to call a Seam action from JSF where that action calls some GWT code.  Hence, your server side Seam code is calling the client side GWT code and you are getting the exception that says `GWT.create() is only usable in client code! It cannot be called, for example, from server code`.  I'm not sure why you're trying to do this.

JSF is a client side technology, written in XHTML.  GWT is also a client side technology written in, well, Java.  I'm not sure how these play together.

On the other hand, there is no reason, as per the link above, why your GWT widgets cannot call your Seam components.  You just need to follow the instructions.